# Android TextView Not being displayed ( Child of RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

My layout.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:tag="cards main container">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/color_white"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/match_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:paddingStart="30dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    tools:text="2nd ODI"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/match_series_separator"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/match_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingStart="5dp"
                    android:text="-"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/series_name"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/match_series_separator"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:paddingStart="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"

                    tools:text="India Tour of SriLanka,5 ODIs,2010"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/team_logo_1"
                        android:tag="image_tag"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_width="65dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/matches"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/score_team_1"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        tools:text="100/3"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/team_logo_1"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/overs_team_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:paddingTop="50dp"
                        android:paddingStart="15dp"
                        tools:text="20"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/team_logo_1" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/team_logo_2"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:tag="image_tag"
                        android:layout_width="65dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/matches"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/score_team_2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        tools:text="100/3"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/team_logo_2"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/overs_team_2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/score_team_2"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:paddingTop="50dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/team_logo_2"
                        tools:text="20"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/match_status_result"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    tools:text="Match in progress/ India won by 3 wickets"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/target_leadby"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    tools:text="Target 189/lead by 100"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_view"
            android:id="@+id/match_preview_summary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="Description of the match thats about to start cause people love to read "/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[ScreenShot from android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKEc6.png)
That's how the image is in the android studio but only the `cardViews` are being displayed on the phone and not the `TextView` with id `android:layout_below="@+id/card_view"`

Using `LinearLayout` doesn't help too.

Changing `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in the parent `RelativeLayout` gives the same result

All the contents of the `CardView` are displayed

If `android:layout_below="@+id/card_view"` is removed the `TextView` is displayed behind the `CardView`

Comment: You should only have one child group view in Card View in your case you have added two children **RelativeLayout** and **LinearLayout** which will overlap each other so add only one group view will solve your issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

**You should only have one child group view in Card View** so make `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` as a parent layout in your `CardView` like below layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/color_white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/match_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:paddingStart="30dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                tools:text="2nd ODI"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/match_series_separator"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/match_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:text="-"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/series_name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/match_series_separator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"

                tools:text="India Tour of SriLanka,5 ODIs,2010"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/team_logo_1"
                    android:tag="image_tag"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/matches"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/score_team_1"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    tools:text="100/3"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/team_logo_1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/overs_team_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:paddingTop="50dp"
                    android:paddingStart="15dp"
                    tools:text="20"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/team_logo_1" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/team_logo_2"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:tag="image_tag"
                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/matches"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/score_team_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    tools:text="100/3"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/team_logo_2"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/overs_team_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/score_team_2"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:paddingTop="50dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/team_logo_2"
                    tools:text="20"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/match_status_result"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                tools:text="Match in progress/ India won by 3 wickets"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/target_leadby"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                tools:text="Target 189/lead by 100"
                />

        </LinearLayout>




       </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```